# find next row in DataFrame based on column values

Tags: python, numpy, pandas

I have a DataFrame with a non-unique sorted datetime index where I need to find the next row after a specific match on some columns of data.

I can find the correct row with DataFrame.query() which gives me a new DataFrame, but I don't know how I can locate where this row is in the original DataFrame. Here is an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

ts_index = [
        datetime.strptime('2016-06-19 22:50:22.189', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'),
        datetime.strptime('2016-06-19 22:50:22.189', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'),
        datetime.strptime('2016-06-19 22:50:22.610', '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f')
        ]
bid_price = [ 77.693, 77.692, 77.692 ]
bid_qty = [ 50.0, 100.0, 50.0 ]
ask_price = [ 77.709, 77.709, 77.709 ]
ask_qty = [ 50.0, 50.0, 50.0 ]

df = pd.DataFrame(index=ts_index, data={'BID_PRICE': bid_price,
    'BID_QTY': bid_qty, 'ASK_PRICE': ask_price, 'ASK_QTY': ask_qty})

most_recent_match = df.query('(BID_PRICE == 77.692) and (BID_QTY == 100.0)').tail(1)

print most_recent_match
```

Is it possible to search / locate a position in a DataFrame using an entire row (index and columns)?

Comment: Can you reset the index, so it is unique, and then identify the index number for the row you're after?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this work?  Just reset the index, and identified the index of the row you're after

```
df = pd.DataFrame(index=ts_index, data={'BID_PRICE': bid_price,
    'BID_QTY': bid_qty, 'ASK_PRICE': ask_price, 'ASK_QTY': ask_qty})

df.reset_index(inplace = True)
most_recent_match = df.query('(BID_PRICE == 77.692) and (BID_QTY == 100.0)').tail(1)

df.ix[most_recent_match.index[0]]
```

Answer (score 1):

You could create a boolean mask, then shift it down by one row:

```
mask = ((df['BID_PRICE'] == 77.692) & (df['BID_QTY'] == 100.0)).shift(1)
df.loc[mask]
```

yields

```
In [17]: df.loc[mask]
Out[17]: 
                         ASK_PRICE  ASK_QTY  BID_PRICE  BID_QTY
2016-06-19 22:50:22.610     77.709     50.0     77.692     50.0
```

Comment: Looks simpler, but doesn't compile for me, and I don't really understand where NaN is coming from in the error:

`ValueError: cannot index with vector containing NA / NaN values`